# How to recover error time to change field type in adminhtml form

Tags: error, addfield

Give the solution for this error...
this error comes when I go to add new item or edit item in admin panel

```
fieldset->addField('dateadded', 'date', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('someadd')->__('Date Added'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'dateadded',
      ));
```

The Error is given below..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add format of date

```
  fieldset->addField('dateadded', 'date', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('someadd')->__('Date Added'),
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'format'  => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT,
      'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
      'class'     => 'validate-date',
      'name'      => 'dateadded',
  ));
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed El Mrabet....I have 1 more question for you ...how to add datepicker in that field..I am very thankfull if you give the answer...

Comment: Ok see my answer I ll updated ok